# (ESLint) JSDoc syntax error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when used with SSHTML files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, nancy

I have a javascript file `[formPost.js]` with below code in a [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy)  based project running a Visual Studio 2017. Solution is not able to detect the formPost.js file.

```js
    'use strict';
    var FORM_NAME = "configure-form";
    var API_URL = "/data/save";
    var RESPONSE_CONTAINER = "response_display";
    var RESULTS_CONTAINER = "results_display";
    /**
    * Checks that an element has a non-empty `name` and `value` property.
    * @@param  {Element} element  the element to check
    * @@return {Bool}             true if the element is an input, false if not
    */
    function isValidElement(element) {
       return element.name && element.value;
    }
    ;
```

I have referenced JS file as follow in master.sshtml file as below

```
<script  type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="/Content/script/formPost.js">
 </script>
```

I see below errors in Visual Studio

[image]

I see the below errors in Browser console

[image]

NOT FOUND MESSAGE in browser.

[image]

Comment: `@@param` and `@@return` should only have one `@` (`@param`, `@return`). See [the documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/). Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.

Comment: The file you've quoted here will not give you an `Unexpected identifier` error: http://jsfiddle.net/L5o4jr1q/

Comment: it gives error when used with SSHTML extension files. Nancy default view engine. Nancy experts might help. so please do not tag as 'non useful to others'

Comment: The code in the question is perfectly valid JavaScript code. Doesn't matter what HTTP framework you're deploying it in, if it supports JavaScript, the posted code will not produce that error. I suggest looking into the problem more deeply.